# How to avoid a NameError when defining a class?

Tags: python, class, nameerror, bioservices

I am writing a class:

```
from bioservices import KEGGParser
class Retrieve_Data():
    def __init__(self):

        def hugo2kegg(self,gene_name,organism):
            s=KEGGParser()
            kegg_gene_entry = s.get(organism+':'+gene_name)
        return kegg_gene_entry


a = Retrieve_Data()
```

But when I run this I get a NameError:

```
NameError: global name 'kegg_gene_entry' is not defined
```

Could somebody tell me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: check the indentation for hugo2kegg.

Comment: The reason I indented the hugo2kegg bit again is because I had an indent error without...

Comment: it does't surprise me that you had an error without an indent here, given that the code in that case would be syntactically incorrect. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Ultimately I would like to produce a class that will contain several methods to look up a HUGO gene symbol and use the python bioservices module to quickly retrieve information about it. This is the first step, i.e. convert a HUGO gene symbol into a UniProt accession ID

Comment: I think I've addressed your primary problem, if so, accept by clicking the checkmark next to my answer and you'll get +2 to your rep. If you have a different question, ask a new one. +1 for the effort.

Comment: ok, well in that case I would suggest you do not need the __init__ at all (as aaron hall is trying to say) you can simply get rid of this line, and then fix the other alignment and then you are golden

Comment: Thanks guys. I think I'm getting the hang of the __init__, but just to double check... The __init__ should only be used if you want to initialize variables to be used later within the class? So technically I could initialize the 'kegg_gene_entry' variable before putting something into it, but that would be a waste of time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your init can't return anything, and there's probably no sense in defining anything in it, if you're not going to use your definition. You probably want to get rid of your `__init__` and do something like this:

```
from bioservices import KEGGParser
class Retrieve_Data():
    def hugo2kegg(self,gene_name,organism):
        s=KEGGParser()
        kegg_gene_entry = s.get(organism+':'+gene_name)
        return kegg_gene_entry


a = Retrieve_Data()
```

You don't need an `__init__`, unless you want things to happen immediately after the object is instantiated.

If you wanted an init that didn't do anything, you would need to have *something* under it:

```
class Retrieve_Data():
    def __init__(self):
        pass # we'll add more later?
```

or

```
class Retrieve_Data():
    def __init__(self):
        '''not doing anything now, maybe we'll write an init later?'''
```

and *then* you could go on to define another function/method for this object.

Comment: I was under the impression that all classes should have an '__init__(self)', even if nothing is there?

Comment: no, that is an incorrect impression. For clarification, see https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html